# Probability of net gain being greater than 0 lottery question

Tags: probability, expected-value, combinatorics, odds

I'm working on some practice exams and I came across a probability question that stumped me.

"In a lottery game, for any lottery ticket bought at random, the chance of winning each prize is listed below. Suppose there are a huge number of lottery tickets such that different lottery tickets can be treated as “independent”.

| Chance | Prize |
| --- | --- |
| 1 in 10 | \$5 |
| 1 in 50 | \$10 |
| 1 in 100 | $20 |

If you were to buy 100 tickets at $1 each, what is the probability that the net gain is greater than 0?

Intuitively, it seems like a multinomial distribution makes sense here, but I'm not sure how to implement it without knowing the number of lottery tickets won and lost for each prize. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Are you required to give a numerical answer or just an expression that would allow you to calculate it?